# Prove that if $f:D=[0,1]\cup [2,3]\to\Bbb R$ such that, $f(x)=0$ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in [2,3],$ then $f$ is continuous on $D.$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The problem in the title arose from solving the problem below, or precisely, while dealing with the validity of *Statement 4.*

Which of the following statements is/are true?

1. There exists a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ$
   such that $f(ℝ)=\mathbb{Q} $.
2. There exists a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ$
   such that $f(ℝ)=\mathbb{Z} $.
3. There exists a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ^2$
   such that $f(ℝ)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2: x^2+y^2=1}\}$.
4. There exists a continuous map $f:[0,1]\cup[2,3]\to \{0,1\}$

My solution is:

*Statement 1 and 2 are false:*

If $f(\Bbb R)=\Bbb Q$ then, $\exists a,b\in \Bbb R$ such that, $f(a)=1,f(b)=2.$ Now, if $a<b$ then we take $I=[a,b]$ else if, $b<a$ we take, $I=[b,a].$ Now, as $f$ is a continuous mapping on $\Bbb R$ so, $f$ is a continuous on $I$ as well. Thus means $f$ is continous on aclosed bounded interval $I$ and Bolzano's Intermediate Value Theorem is applicable. This further means that, as, $f(a)=1\lt \sqrt 2\lt f(b)=2,$ and $a,b\in I$ so there exists a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ or, $\exists c\in I\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $f(c)=\sqrt 2.$

This means, that $f(c)=\sqrt 2\in f(\Bbb R)=\Bbb Q,$  a contradiction. So, $f(\Bbb R)\neq \Bbb Q.$

Repeating the same procedure with only changing $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Z$ we can show that statement $2$ is incorrect as well.

*Statement 3 and 4 are true:*

We define $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ for all $t\in\Bbb R.$ We note that, $f(\Bbb R)=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}.$ Now, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ as $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are continuous on $\Bbb R.$ So, we have proved the existence of a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ^2$
such that $f(ℝ)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2: x^2+y^2=1}\}$.

If $f:D=[0,1]\cup [2,3]\to\Bbb R$ such that, $f(x)=0$ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in [2,3],$  then $f$ is continuous on $D.$ Looking at the graph of $f$ we can say, that $f$ is a continuous mapping. So again, we have, proved that there exists a continuous map $f:D=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\to \{0,1\}.$

---

However, as can be seen from the solution I have not given a rigorous prove while dealing with statement $4$, to show that, $f$ is continuous in $D.$ I can't think of a rigorous way to show this.

Comment: For 4 you could also give the simpler function $f:D\to \{0,1\}$ given by $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in D$. It's very easy to prove that every constant function is continuous.

Comment: @jjagmath Yeah, you're so true. Never thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: This however could be not the original intent of the exercise. Considering the other 3 statements I'd guess that the idea of the exercise is to give the function you post.

Comment: Your function in 4 is continuous as well. In general if a function is defined on two intervals which are at a positive distance from each other then if $f$ is continuous on either interval it is continuous on their union. Another funny way could be to extend the function to $[0,3]$ by setting $f(x)=x-1$ on $  [1,2].$ The extended function is continuous on $[0,3]$ so is its restriction to the union of the intervals.

Comment: @jjagmath If you consider posting your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: I think to argue in a simple elementary way you can just use $\epsilon - \delta$ criterion for some $a\in D$ and you have to consider different cases of where $a$ can be. But if you know the characterization of continuous functions that $f$ is continuous iff for all open sets $U$ in the co-domain, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open then that will do the job much faster.